# VueJS importing external java Script and call methods in created life cycle hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I import an external java script file to a Vue component and How to call a method which is in that external file inside the created life cycle hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the function exported in your external js file:

```
function myMethod() { .... }

export default myMethod;
```

And then import in your vue file and use:

```
import myMethod from "external-file.js"
```

Now, you can use `myMethod` inside `created` hook:

```
created() {
  myMethod();
}
```

For more help: check [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! =) But I have another problem I imported to my vue component and other than calling the created() hook I tried to call it directly from a click event. "<button type="button" name="button" @click="myMethod">My Button</button>" then it gives the error "Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined" How do I call it from a button or can I register it as a normal method in my vue component.